# Cookie with a path specified is not set via javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a local host called "myproject". When i try to set a cookie for resource "myproject/someresource" like this:

```
document.cookie = "mycookie=somevalue; path=/someresource";
```

IE does not set this cookie. But it does if i do not use path parameter:

```
document.cookie = "mycookie=somevalue";
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: "IE does not set this cookie.": How did you validate this? Also, sure that the path `/someresource` exists?

Comment: in developers tools js console `document.cookie` returns nothing. and yes i'm sure that resource exists

Answer (score 0):

according http://forum.de.selfhtml.org/archiv/2009/7/t189018/ the site must be within the specifed path. So I think you have to add a slash at the last position and you site must be in "http://mydomain.com/somesource/filename.datatype"

Comment: i tried to call this host `www.myproject.com` it did not help. same with the path, i tried various combinations but all in vain.